# Worsened image quality and false colours after georeferencing

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, color

When I georeference a map of vegetation types (about 20 colours, each representing a certain vegetation) the quality of the georeferenced map is really bad and some colours have changed (e.g. black becomes white), which makes it almost impossible to recognise certain types.

I did the "usual" procedure: transformation type: linear, method: nearest neighbor.
For source I tried jpeg & tiff, same bad result.

Any suggestions how to improve the quality of the map and the originality of the map?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about QGIS, but ArcMap often defaults to a "standard deviations" stretched colour ramp when you add a newly georeferenced image. This often distorts the colours, although your example sounds pretty extreme. The solution in ArcMap is to set the 'stretch type' from **Standard deviations** to **None**. Perhaps the same applies in QGIS?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but i does not work. However I just got the shape, so problem avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of an old thread, but for an extra $.02, I solved this problem by ensuring the Limits (minimum/maximum) setting was set to "Minimum/maximum" in the Rasters section of the Rendering tab of QGIS settings. Also, in the same settings area, the Green Band setting was set to 0 when I initially came across the problem so I set it to 2. May also want to play around with the Raster properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

This problem may arise if the source file has paletted colours.

During reprojection, QGIS tries to interpolate between original cell values, and this fails when you only have a bunch of paletted colours.

So expand your raster file to RGB, which allws for contiguos interpolating.

`Raster -> Convert -> Translate` has a dropdown box that you can change frm grey to RGB.

Or use `gdal_translate -expand rgb` directly.